# DS9 Odo's perception

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, character-development

I'm still on my DS9 kick, and one thing struck me.
Odo is a shape-shifter whose natural state is a liquid. I know there is one episode where he basically outlines that he keeps human form because it makes interacting with others easier. So, much like his face, hair, uniform, etc, his eyes are merely there for appearance.

Also, there are plenty of instances where Odo takes the shape of say, a drink cart, or a painting, and is able to sneak up behind someone while they are not looking. This, I would think, indicates his perceptions are not dependent upon his form.

 So my question is ultimately: If Odo doesn't require eyes, Why can't he 'see' behind himself if the eyes are merely an affectation? Or is his vision limited to say.. a 180 degree radius, and how do we know? (Specifically I was just watching an episode where Jake and Nog sneak BEHIND Odo to avoid beeing seen.. )

Comment: Related: [How can Odo speak?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/30570/2565)

Comment: this is a fantastic observation!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Out of universe the explanation is simply poor planning. There are a lot of things about the DS9 shape-shifters that don't make sense or are at least inconsistent with how they describe themselves.

In universe, there are 3 possibilities I can think of:

1. Odo does see Jake and Nog, but simply pretends he doesn't. Throughout the series, you get the feeling that Odo knows a lot more about the criminal happenings on DS9 than he lets on. He does this for strategic reasons. If he were to bust every minor offense, it would distract him from more serious crimes as well as tip his hand to the major criminal elements. There are also rare occasions where he deliberately lets people get away with minor offenses because he feels sorry for or indebted to them (e.g. Quark smuggling Denevan Crystals).
2. Odo theoretically has vision across his entire body surface, but his observation abilities are limited by what he's capable of mentally processing. So if he's focusing intently in one direction, he develops a sort of mental tunnel vision and might not notice something happening in the opposite direction. [Change blindness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_blindness) in humans can also be caused in a similar fashion.
3. When changelings become solids, they actually become indistinguishable from the genuine article by all known scanners. So perhaps when Odo becomes a hawk, he has the visual acuity of a hawk, but also can't see from his feathers. However, this doesn't explain why Odo can see and hear when he's, say, a drink cup. So this is the weakest explanation.

Comment: Odo may _perceive_ everything in a changeling form, but that doesn't necessarily mean he _sees_ everything as we do. Odo is likely not limited to the five senses that humans are in his liquid form, but perhaps he does use them. As for a drink cup, maybe he relies on his other 43 senses....? :P

Comment: +1 primarily for #1 - Jake and Nog aren't even criminals

Comment: +1 for the poor planning.  In at least one episode Odo is knocked unconscious by the trademark TV blow to the back of the head.  Even if he couldn't see the guy behind him, you'd think a shapeshifter would be indifferent to being whacked by some thug with a sap.  It would have been great if Odo had just turned around and looked at the guy, but down he went.

Comment: Poor planning indeed. Let's not forget Odo was afraid of Bat'leth's in "Way of the Warrior", even though they should have just gone through him.

Comment: I could see him being afraid of bat'leths only if when a part of him was lopped off it was permanent. I don't know if its true or not.. but I dont' think I ever saw him split in two...

Comment: +1 for this, but I'd really like to know, is there any point during the show where odo describes his sensory perceptions? Could this augment/help this answer? If so please edit that in.

Comment: @Arammil: Super late reply, but the most we get is him describing in vague new-agey terms how he feels like (better understands) the things he shifts into, including inanimate objects. He never describes what his perception is like, but it's highly suggestive that both his thoughts/impulses and senses become like the object he imitates.

Comment: @Arammil: And he does in fact have pieces removed from him by Dr. Bashir (by drawing "blood" which immediately turns into his natural golden liquid form when it leaves his body). He dislikes this and worries about losing the piece, but Bashir promises to return it back to him later on. So he can definitely re-integrate with removed pieces.

Comment: @KyleJones I believe the episode where Odo is knocked out was set during the time Odo had lost his shapeshifting abilities and was genuinely human. It's not a contradiction to the internal consistency.